# jsPlumb anchors positions

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am trying to customize jsPlumb to draw graphs, with all arrows going downwards, with connection-sources from the bottom-side of a container and connection-targets to the top-side of a container somewhere down the page.
I use:

```
instance.connect({ source:"sourceDiv", target:"targetDiv" , anchors:["Bottom", "Top"] });
```

which works fine except one little issue...

All arrows will originate from the **middle** of a bottom-side and terminate at the **middle** of a top-side.

When there are many arrows going to/from the same container, I would rather like the anchors **evenly spread out** along the top-sides and bottom-sides.

From the docs, I tried things like:

```
instance.makeSource("sourceDiv", { anchor: "Continuous" });
instance.makeTarget("targetDiv", { anchor: "Continuous" });
```

or (with jQuery):

```
instance.makeSource($("#sourceDiv"), { anchor: "Continuous" });
instance.makeTarget($("#targetDiv"), { anchor: "Continuous" });
```

But apparently not the right syntax... get errors like:

```
jsPlumb: fire failed for event connection : TypeError: info.connection.getOverlay(...) is null
```

Need help to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors are associated with endpoint. When connecting elements, endpoints are created automatically, but making an element source & target, doesn't create endpoint unless a connection is created & hence, the code fails.

```
https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/anchors.html
```

Instead of making element `source` & `target`, `addEndpoint` to that element as follows :

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("someDiv", {
    endpoint:"Dot",
    isSource:true,
    isTarget:false,
    anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Square", anchorCount:150 }]
});
```

Comment: Hmm... so in what order should I do things?
Now, I created the elements with html-divs, then tried to modify their anchors positions, then .connect() them.
What is the correct sequence?
Should I still use .connect()? 
Or some other way?
(Not easy to grasp the concepts of this framework... I guess some picture illustrations in the docs would have helped...)

Comment: `jsPlumb` is very flexible, allowing the creation of connections directly between elements & external endpoints. I personally prefer this [example](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/flowchart/dom.html) and here's the [code ](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/flowchart/demo.js).